# Selecting only 8 rows from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently developing a social network. I would like to have a MySQL query that selects the first 8 rows from a table. Like let's say I have 100 rows in a table, how would I select the first 8?

Comment: Do you use ORM or raw query with cursor? Post your code where you are fetch data from DB.

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE (`user`='$user') OR (`user2`='$user')"); That's what I use, I need it to select the first 8 users to display on profiles

Comment: @xGh0stSn1p3r Write `SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8 FROM friends WHERE (user='$user') OR (user2='$user')` instead of selecting all columns in table using an asterisk.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: What I want to do is, let's say there are 10 users in my database, test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10. I want to select test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 to get their information and display them on the friends section on a profile, as a preview.

Comment: Columns or rows? You need to be specific, and provide more information.

Comment: Rows, like select the first 8 usernames on the table

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user='$user'
OR user2='$user' LIMIT 8")
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. I can't believe i forgot all about the limit thing. Now just gotta add order by `id` desc and it'll be perfect!